# Laravel 5.2 - creating a model from a variable

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to access dynamically models so that I can get the count for each of them depending on which string I pass to the function.
This is what my function in the controller looks like:

```
public function numberOf(Request $request){
    $modelName = $request['option'];
    $model = new $modelName;
    $data = $model->count();

    return json_encode($data);
  }
```

But when I pass a string, like in this case `'Article'`  I get an error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Article' not found

Even though I am calling it in the controller:

```
use App\Article;
```

Comment: Did you set up the name spaces?

Comment: Yes, and it is working fine in the other function in the same controller when I am using Article model like this: $numberOfArticles = Article::count();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add App to model name, so that my function looks like this now and everything works fine now:

```
$modelName = 'App\\'.$request['option'];
$model = new $modelName;
$data = $model->count();

return json_encode($data);
```